# ASP.NET Core Web App change/add items to page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

So I am trying to use my knowledge of ASP.NET to use ASP.NET Core but I am struggling to figure out how to edit my page from my code behind.

One my cshtml page I have the following header.

```
<h2 id="QuestionLabel" runat="server">
</h2>
```

In the related cshtml.cs class I tried the following to edit the text within.

```
QuestionLabel.Text = "text"
```

This appears to not be how it is done in ASP.NET core but I can't find the Microsoft docs for something like this. I also have an empty div that I want to add items to in the back-end and can't seem to find out how to that here either.

Any links to the Microsoft docs related would be appreciated.

Comment: Hello @Klopsftein54, you can start from here [Get started with ASP.NET Core MVC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/start-mvc?WT.mc_id=dotnet-35129-website&view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio)

Comment: @tontonsevilla Thank you! This appears to be exactly what I needed. I was on the right document but in the wrong section, hence why it was no help. Thank you so much though!